# zooming in on an image with css3 (wabkit based issue)

Tags: css, webkit, zooming, transition

Here is the problem with the code bellow. I want to create zoom-like effect with css. I am adding the classes zoomIn or zoomOut with jquery on certain events, which is not important right now.

The problem is that in Chrome and Safari (webkit based) the zoom in and out start from 0. In firefox for instance the transition starts from the current image height and extends to 1160px in this case. The webkit browsers however seem to handle things different and start the transition from 0 to 1160px

I ain't got no clever way to solve this so please help

Cheers

The images have also a class of 'full'

```
.full       {display:block;position:absolute;width:100%;top:0;left:0;}

.zoomIn{ 
 top:0;left:0;
 box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in; 
  -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in; 
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in; 
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in; 
  height: 1160px !important;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -960px !important;
  margin-top: -670px !important;
  top: 50%;
  width: 1920px;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
  -moz-transform: scale(1.2);
  -o-transform: scale(1.2);
  transform: scale(1.2);
  -ms-transform: scale(1.2);

  }

.zoomOut { 
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in; 
   -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in;  
   transition: all 0.2s ease-in; 
   -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in; 
   -moz-transform: scale(1);
   margin-left: 0 ;margin-top: 0;
   -webkit-transform: scale(1);
   -o-transform: scale(1);
   transform: scale(1);
   -ms-transform: scale(1);

  }
```